# Use Like% in CouchDB Doctrine Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, lucene, couchdb, doctrine-odm

I'm using this [bundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCouchDBBundle) and I wanto to find my element by `%LIKE%` mysql

My document is like this:

```
{
   "_id": "60a403542a2b7d44bf84ed569d1e6efe",
   "_rev": "1-9e1ed380dd91ac8c835ef0f8e152f0a8",
   "type": "mytype",
   "doctrine_metadata": {
       "indexes": [
           "name",
       ]
   },
   "name": "barfoo",

}
```

I want to Find all element that begin with `barfo`

I saw this [link](http://doctrine-couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/lucene-queries.html), but I don't know if this is a right Solution.
How Can I do `Like` query in couchDb + symfony2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't `%Like%` in couchDb (1.6.1), but you can use startkey and endkey.

You have to create a view like:

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.type = 'myType') {
        emit(doc.name, doc.name);
    }
}
```

with name for example `people`.

For example and simplicity

```
Designname = people
viewname = people
```

After that you can do This Curl

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:5984/db/_design/people/_view/people?startkey="foo"&endkey="foo\ufff0"'
```

In this way you can find all element that begin with foo.

Why \ufff0 ? Check this [link](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation)

> String Ranges
>
> If you need start and end keys that encompass every string with a
>   given prefix, it is better to use a high value unicode character, than
>   to use a 'ZZZZ' suffix.
>
> That is, rather than:
>
> startkey="abc"&endkey="abcZZZZZZZZZ" You should use:
>
> startkey="abc"&endkey="abc\ufff0"

How Can you do this in Symfony ?

If you want to create View by Symfony
You can Create the view in `yourapp/AppBundle/CouchDocument/View/PeopleView.php`

```
<?php

namespace yourapp\AppBundle\CouchDocument\View;

use Doctrine\CouchDB\View\DesignDocument;

class PeopleView implements DesignDocument
{

    public function getData()
    {
        $people = <<<'JS'
function (doc) {
        if (doc.type = 'myType') {
            emit(doc.name, doc.name);
        }
    }
JS;

        return array(
            'views' => array(
                'people' => array(
                    'map' => $people,
                ),
            )
        );

    }
}
```

and in your controller you can do something like this

```
/**
 * @Route("/testPeople/{code}", name="test_people")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Template("myAppBundle:People:test_query.html.twig")
 */
public function testPeopleAction($code)
{

    $dm = $this->container->get(
        'doctrine_couchdb.odm.default_document_manager'
    );
    $peopleView = new PeopleView();
    $client = $this->container->get('doctrine_couchdb.odm.default_document_manager');
    $view = $client->createDesignDocument('people', $peopleView);

    $relatedObjects = $dm->createNativeQuery('people', 'people')
        ->setStartKey($code)
        ->setEndKey($code . "\xEF\xBF\xB0")
        ->execute();
    $a = array();
    foreach ($relatedObjects as $doc) {
        $a[] = $doc['value'] //it is your results
    }

    return array(
        'results' => $a
    );
}
```

I saw the unitTest inside `vendor/doctrine/couchdb/tests/Doctrine/Tests/CouchDB/CouchDBClientTest.php` to find something to usefull

I Don't Know if it is the best way, but for me it works :)